# Migrating AWS Amplify App from DynamoDB to Postgresql Aurora Serverless V1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds, aws-amplify, aws-aurora-serverless

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've developed an application using AWS Amplify, and currently, it utilizes DynamoDB as the default database. However, I'm planning to migrate the data to Postgresql Aurora Serverless V1. Could you provide guidance on the steps and best practices for achieving this migration seamlessly?

Here are a few specific questions I have:

What tools or AWS services should I use for exporting data from DynamoDB to Postgresql?
Are there any compatibility issues or considerations I need to be aware of during the migration process?
How can I update the Amplify configuration to use Postgresql Aurora Serverless V1 as the new backend?
I appreciate any insights, code snippets, or documentation references that can help me navigate this transition successfully. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I attempted to update the data source in the AWS Amplify configuration to point to my Postgresql Aurora Serverless database hosted on AWS RDS. However, when I did this, data transfer doesn't occur, and the application breaks. Can you help me understand why this might be happening and provide guidance on how to resolve it?

Specifically:

1- What could be causing the failure in data transfer when switching the data source to my Postgresql Aurora Serverless database in AWS RDS?
2- Are there any specific configurations or steps I need to take in AWS Amplify to ensure a seamless transition to the new database?